# SmartPSS for Dahua DVR black screen

Tags: wine, camera

On a kubuntu 16.04: [SmartPSS](https://us.dahuasecurity.com/product/smartpss/) for Dahua DVR & NVR installed successfully (wine). Can add device (DVR/NVR/IPCamera). But after login successfully into device, camera don't show anything except a complete black screen with camera number and date-time.

Comment: Have you checked at WineHQ, https://appdb.winehq.org/ if that application works well in wine?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but; did you connected the camera? Maybe you're opening a disconnected channel. Try with Live View (or something like it's called) and go dragging and dropping every camera detected. Maybe it's a bad configuration on the DVR.
I successfully made it work in Linux Mint 17 32 bits with Wine 1.6